# How to know which regex patterns from multiple used matched string in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm matching multiple regex patterns vs very longs strings (up to 10e8 characters). Is there a way to know which of my regex patterns report match in Python? Or should I rather do regex separately for each pattern?

```
pat=re.compile('C[GT]GG|A[AT]TA|T[TG]TA')
for m in pat.finditer(longString):
  print m.start(), m.end()
  # how to know which pat matched?
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
m.group()
```

to see which part of regex matched your input.

```
>> for m in pat.finditer('pat290'):
...     print m.start(), m.end(), m.group()
...
0 4 pat2

>>> for m in pat.finditer('pat3789'):
...     print m.start(), m.end(), m.group()
...
0 4 pat3

>>> for m in pat.finditer('some-pat1234567'):
...     print m.start(), m.end(), m.group()
...
5 9 pat1
```

Comment: thanks anubhava, actually I know about m.group(), but my patterns are a bit more complicated than 'pat1', it maybe something more like 'A[AC][GC]T'. I have specified it in the question now.

Comment: Hmm I don't think you can get `C[GT]GG` from matched results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`lastindex`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.lastindex) (or [`lastgroup`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.lastgroup)) attribute of `re` match objects, which reports the index (or group name) of the last matched group.

However you have to modify your regular expression in order to transform each subexpression into a group, by enclosing them between brackets:

```
pat=re.compile('(C[GT]GG)|(A[AT]TA)|(T[TG]TA)')
for m in pat.finditer(longString):
    print m.start(), m.end(), 'group index:', m.lastindex
```

If you like to use symbolic names (thus improving readability), the pattern syntax is a little more complicated:

```
pat=re.compile('(?P<C_CG_GG>C[GT]GG)|(?P<A_AT_TA>A[AT]TA)|(?P<T_TG_TA>T[TG]TA)')
for m in pat.finditer(longString):
    print m.start(), m.end(), 'group index:', m.lastindex, 'group name:', m.lastgroup
```